# Magento invalid cron expression

Tags: magento, cron

One of the extensions I have installed in Magento has a cron scheduled with the expression `0 0 4 1/1 * ? *`. From what I've gathered means it should run every day at 4am.

When the Magento cron runs I get an error report saying: `Invalid cron expression: 0 0 4 1/1 * ? *`.  I haven't been able to find any information on the valid format for Magento crons. Should they only have 5 fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Magento uses [SimpleTrigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05) format (the one with 5 fields), however your cron here is in [CronTrigger](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06) format.

I'm not an expert in cron but I think your cron is setting a daily schedule to run at 4 AM (check it out [here](http://www.cronmaker.com/)); Just try to restyle it in the [SimpleTrigger format](http://cron.nmonitoring.com/cron-generator.html) which would be:

```
0 4 * * *
```

Comment: Interesting, but where is the *"SimpleTrigger format"* documented? The reference you give in your answer only shows API examples for Java code and not a format description of a cron expression.

Answer (score 2):

The cron expression in Magento 1 can have five or six columns (fields). Column separator is white-space.

If there are less than five or more than six columns, you'll get a **Mage_Cron_Exception** with the message *"Invalid cron expression: <expression>"* in which *<expression>* is replaced with the verbatim string value of the configuration option that is getting parsed. This is the exact exception message you have in your question.

This most generic **Mage_Cron_Exception** message is given if the fundamental white-space parsing into the right number of columns fails or if any of the columns can't be parsed as any of the following cron expressions:

- `*`  - ALL match
- `...,...` - multiple options (each one of the comma-separated must validate again)
- `...\...` - modulus (two elements, second one must be numeric)
- `...-...` - range (from - to) of numeric data, three-letter English abbreviations of month and weekday names are translated into their numeric counterpart (using "mon" for month will result in 1 (January), "sun" for month as 0 (undefined but not invalid) etc.).
- *number*, *abbreviation* - just a numeric value or a three-letter weekday or month abbreviation (case-insensitive, first three letters count, e.g. *"MaYbE"* will be hashed as *"may"* resulting in the look-up of the number five (5)).

If on any of these (or in case of the multiple options, any of the sub-options) results in some parsing problem, the **Mage_Cron_Exception** with the message *"Invalid cron expression"* is suffixed with additional information like:

- *", expecting 'from-to' structure: <expression>"*
- *", expecting 'match/modulus': <expression>"*
- *", expecting numeric modulus: <expression>"*
- ... and so on

Cron expression parsing is done in *`Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule::getCronExprArr()`* and *`Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule::matchCronExpression()`*.

```
0 0 4 1/1 * ? *
```

In your case the cron expression has a correct number of fields (six) but the value "`?`" you have for the fifth column is not parsed in a Magento cron expression resulting in the generic message (as it's not identified as any of the field value formats).

The format is a subset of the [CRON expression (as given per Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression). The sixth field (year) can be set but is never taken into consideration.