# Magento Cron Job Error 1:Invalid cron expression

Tags: php, cron, magento-1.9

Hello I am having the Issue with Cron Job Below is the log generated for the error can any one explain me how to fix it?

Magento Version:1.9.2

> 1:Invalid cron expression

Trace:

```
0 /home/kiabza/public_html/stage/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Schedule.php(68): Mage::exception('Mage_Cron', '1:Invalid cron ...')
1 /home/kiabza/public_html/stage/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(184): Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule->setCronExpr('1')
2 /home/kiabza/public_html/stage/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(146): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_generateJobs(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Array)
3 /home/kiabza/public_html/stage/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model/Observer.php(75): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->generate()
4 /home/kiabza/public_html/stage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1358): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
5 /home/kiabza/public_html/stage/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1337): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
6 /home/kiabza/public_html/stage/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
7 /home/kiabza/public_html/stage/cron.php(77): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
8 {main}
```

Comment: Can you show how you're creating your cron? Without any information, I can only point you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224534/magento-invalid-cron-expression and https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/80886/magento-1-7-community-invalid-cron-expression

Comment: * * * * * php /home/kiabza/public_html/stage/cron.php

This is the cron job command I am using to run cron job every minute in cPanel.

Comment: Hear is one of the error log report:
http://stage.kiabza.com/errors/report.php?id=804662324719